# Find what program accessed a kernel module

Tags: logs, kernel-modules, video, syslog

How do I access a list of users/programs that accessed a certain module?

I run:

```
lsmod | grep ^uvcvideo
```

This returns this line when no application is using my video camera:

```
uvcvideo               86016  0
```

Well, I have something running that when "0" at the end of the line turns to anything but 0 (in practice this is usually 1) it sends me a notification that my camera is in use.

I want to know if there is a log of programs that turned that 0 to a 1, or  which modules are accessed when/how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, there is no log file for this.  There are tools you can use to make one though!

The kernel has a built-in tracepoint for the try_module_get() function.  That's the function that increases the reference count of a module.  This tracepoint is in the `module` subsystem and is called `module_get`.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448999/is-there-a-way-to-figure-out-what-is-using-a-linux-kernel-module/449856 (long read).

To get you started, you can try `perf trace -a --no-syscalls -e module:module_get -e module:module_put`.  This shows the program name, but it [does not show the PID](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/483189/a-command-to-show-tracepoints-live-which-includes-the-pid).