# Is there a command to show tracepoints "live", which includes the PID?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, perf, tracing

I have tried looking at the documentation for `perf script`, `perf trace`, and `trace-cmd`, including the list of commands in "SEE ALSO".

I can trace e.g. `sched:sched_process_exec` "live" using `perf trace -a --no-syscalls -e sched:sched_process_exec`.  However, it only shows the process *name* (e.g. `ls`).  It does not show the PID, unless the tracepoint has a specific parameter for it.  `perf script` always shows the PID, but it does not show live output; it shows the contents of a `perf.data` file.

I don't need this to be a single command, like `btrace` is for `blktrace`.  I am  happy to use a pipeline, analogous to `blktrace -d /dev/sda -o - | blkparse -i -`.

(Both of the above commands show PIDs :-).  It is frustrating to see the `blktrace` family of commands, which also use trace events, can print live output in the same format as they can print recorded traces.  I can't find such power in the general-purpose tracing tools!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perf record -a --no-syscalls -e sched:sched_process_exec sh -c read | perf script
```

(`sh -c read` provides a way to stop this trace, just hit Enter.  If I omit this command and try to interrupt the pipeline with ctrl+C, my output is lost, probably because it also interrupts `perf script`).

However this output is not "live", due to buffering.  E.g. running the above command shows nothing, but hitting enter causes it to stop and show a line for the exec() of `sh`.  `blktrace` has [special-case code](http://git.kernel.dk/cgit/blktrace/tree/blktrace.c?h=blktrace-1.2.0#n2254) to handle output to a pipe, including disabling the default C stdio buffering.  Attempting to run `perf record` under the `unbuffer` command gives the error "incompatible file format"; I presume the error comes from `perf script`.

---

> `man perf-report`
>
> ...
>
> OPTIONS
>
> `-i, --input=` Input file name. (default: perf.data **unless stdin is a fifo**)